# Groovy convert sql.eachRow results to List

Tags: groovy, groovy-sql

```
def List_Sftp = sql.eachRow(SftpQuery){ row ->
    if(row[4]=="SFTP")  {
        def names= row.collect{ "${row[0]},${row[1]} ${row[3]} ,${row[4]},${row[5]},${row[6]},${row[7]}" }
        println names
    }

    if(row[4]=="ROSETTANET"){
        def names= row.collect{ "${row[0]},${row[1]},${row[2]},${row[4]},${row[5]},${row[6]},${row[7]}" }
        println names
    }

}
```

Output above code is

```
[2.01.00,SAMSUNG,123,XYZ,7C7,file1.xml,zzzz]
[2.01.00,SAMSUNG,123,XYZ,7C7,file2.xml,yyyy]
```

I can't iterate this out as a list. Suggest how to convert this output to

```
[2.01.00,SAMSUNG,123,XYZ,7C7,file1.xml,zzzz,2.01.00,SAMSUNG,123,XYZ,7C7,file2.xml,yyyy]
```

Comment: Use rows() method instead of eashRow

Answer (score 0):

```
def all = []
sql.eachRow(SftpQuery){ row ->
   all.addAll row
}

println all
```

In `all` you will have all results in a single iterateble list

Comment: use `rows` in favour of mutating a list in a loop

Comment: the op wants to concatenate all rows into a single list. so it doesn't really matter if you use `rows` or `eachRow`

Comment: It is a matter of efficiency and readability. `def List_Sftp = sql.rows(SftpQuery)` is both more efficient and more readable than your four lines that contain a closure execution for each row.